# Div height not filling the screen size when adding images inside it

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am adding two images with a text inside a div which should occupy the whole left side of the screen. When I add the second image at the bottom. Half of the image goes out of the div and and the height of the div is not extended.
The screenshot is the output I am getting

Here is the code:

```
<section className="App">
      <div className="First-Half">
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="Lacazette-Image">
            <img alt="Lacazette" src={Lacazette}></img>
          </div>
          <div className="Arsenal-Fans">
            Arsenal Fans
          </div>
          <div className="Celebrate-Image">
            <img alt="Celebrations" src={Celebrations}></img>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kanit|Lobster|Mansalva&display=swap');

.App {
  font-family: 'Lobster', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

.First-Half {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.Arsenal-Fans {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  left: 74%;
  top: 58%;
  font-family: 'Lobster', sans-serif;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.22;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: rgba(249, 246, 246, 0.97);
}

.Lacazette-Image img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border: solid 1px #707070;
}

.Celebrate-Image img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 67%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border: solid 1px #707070;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-bhaskara-6pj9y[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using

```
position: absolute;
```

on the images, you are removing them from the flow of the page, and the parent div will not grow with them. Instead of using absolute positioning for layout, you should consider using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). These will also help you create a responsive site that will work well on different device sizes.

Here is a short example of how to use Flexbox for layout: https://jsfiddle.net/9swka2gL/

Edit: I like what @novruzrhmv said, but as in the example above, I recommend keeping the whole `<h1>` together if possible, both for SEO reasons and to make it easier if you collapse to 1 column on mobile. One way to do that is to force just the h1 wrapper to overflow the column as in the example above.

Comment: The second image in the left column is not being shown to take the full width of the left side. It is centered.

Comment: Updated answer with new jsfiddle link in which I made the placeholder images larger. If an image is centered instead of filling, that is probably happening because the image resolution is not high enough. The browser will not display the image at larger than its "intrinsic" size.

Answer (score 0):

Add following codes to your .css file;

```
.Arsenal-Fans-In-Lebanon-Image img{width:100%}
```

Comment: This image has nothing to do with the left half

Comment: in demo one image on left side and the image is seem like normal.

Comment: Just open the browser on a complete screen

Comment: I use browser on a complete screen i still on left side one image, on right side one image(arsenal logo). Please add image for your expected output.

Comment: i recreate your project template because your code sctructure is wrong. check : https://codepen.io/novruzrhmv/pen/VwZOBJO?editors=1100